# $L^p$ norm for a random vector

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $X$ be a random vector, i.e. $X(\omega) = (X_1(\omega),\dots,X_n(\omega))$ where $\omega \in \Omega$.

How does one define the $L^p$ norm of $X$ over $\Omega$? Would it be something like

$\int_{\Omega} |X|^p dP$ where $|X|$ refers to the Euclidean norm of the vector $X$?

I cannot seem to find any information related to this online.

Furthermore, if the above definition is legitimate, does $L^p$ convergence of a random vector have the same implications as $L^p$ convergence of a random variable? I.e., does this imply convergence in probability, distribution, etc.?

Help appreciated, especially links to relevant resources which are convenient to cite. Thanks!

Comment: $X$ is just a function, you can endow the space with a norm $\|X\| = \sqrt[p]{\int_\Omega \|X(\omega)\|^p d P(\omega)}$.

Comment: Yes. Just put the $p$-th root over it.

Comment: Many use the $p$-norm on $\mathbb R^n$ for the underlying vector norm $|\cdot|$.

Comment: And convergence in $L^p$ is the same as convergence in $p$-th mean (by definition).

Comment: OK, I see. Do you guys happen to have references I can cite? 

Also, does $L^p$ convergence of a random vector defined above imply convergence in cross-moments if the range of the random vector is compact?

Comment: @TomasJorovic what do you mean by in cross-moment? Btw. The underlying vector norm is not relevant beside in case of $L^2$. It is rather your personal taste...

Comment: I see. For example, $E(X_1^2 X_2)$ where $X_1$ and $X_2$ are components of the random vector $X$

Comment: @TomasJorovic assuming the sequence of random vectors converges with sufficiently high order in mean. Yes. Just use Hölder inequality